# How many number of primes below n such that they are sum of consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a number `n`, how many number of primes are there such that each of them is equal to  $$\sum_{k=0}^z p_k $$ where z is some natural number and $p_k$ is nth prime number i.e, $p_0=2$?

For example, if `n=20` , there are 2 primes `5,17` , they satisfy the above rules as follows:

5 = 2+ 3

17 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7

So , is there any formula or any efficient method to identify how many such primes are there below a huge number `n`?

Comment: How large is $n$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A013918 should be of interest.

Comment: I'm confused about your use of $n$ and $k$. Assuming $p_k$ is the $k$'th prime, your first sentence contains an $n$ that plays no role... (Though I think you mean to use $n$ as an upper bound.)

Comment: @Marcus Stuhr upto 12billion

Comment: @Daan Michiels, `n` plays no role like you said, it's just an upper bound

Comment: @Barry Cipra, exactly I'd like to know how many such primes exist below a number

Comment: @PruthviRaj, for the number you cite, $12$ billion, the answer can be found in the table linked to at the OEIS entry I mentioned:  There are $2182$ primes less than $12$ billion that are the sum of the first $k$ primes for some $k$.  Note, however, that the OEIS entry counts $2$ among them, whereas you seem not to.  (You point to $5=2+3$ and $17=2+2+5+7$ as the only primes less than $20$ that are the sum of consecutive primes.)  If you don't count $2$, then the answer to your question with $12$ billion as the upper bound is $2181$.

Comment: For reference, go to https://oeis.org/A013918/b013918.txt and scroll down to "line" 2183 and observe that it's the first entry larger than $12$ billion, but then note that the entry in line 1 is $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A heuristic approach:  [OEIS A007504](https://oeis.org/A007504) lists the sums of the first primes and says the $k^{\text{th}}$ entry is about $\frac 12k^2\log k$ The maximum $k$ that you allow comes from $\frac 12k^2\log k=n$.  We can do one step of fixed point iteration to say $\log k \approx \log \sqrt {2n}, k \approx \sqrt{\frac {2n}{\log \sqrt {2n}}}$.  Now if we say the chance of a number $q$ being prime is $\frac 1{\log q}$ we get an approximation up to $n$ that is $$\sum_{i=2}^{\sqrt{\frac {2n}{\log \sqrt {2n}}}}\frac 1{\log( \frac 12i^2\log i)}$$ where I started at $2$ because it blows up at $1$

Comment: unfortunately we will probably never be able to prove it ? I always wondered if there is any chance to prove that a wide class of sequence really have an asymptotic density $\frac{1}{\ln a_n}$ for the primality of its elements

Comment: @Ross Millikan , wow thanks , is there anyway to improve it's accuracy?, currently it gives $2168$ for $12billion$ whereas the actual answer should be $2182$

Comment: There are some more terms listed in the OEIS entry and you can do some more iteration to get a better upper limit.  If you actually solve $\frac 12k^2 \log k=12E9$ you get an upper limit of 47222 while my approximation gives 44813.  That may solve your problem.  Using the additional terms gives an upper limit of 45490 per [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2*(log(n)%2Blog(log(n))-3%2F2)%2F2%3D12*10%5E9)

Comment: Using $45490$ as the upper limit in the above sum gives $2197.61$ per [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Flog(i%5E2*log(i)%2F2)+from+2+to+45490&rawformassumption=%22i%22+-%3E+%22Variable%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FunClash%22,+%22log%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Log%22%7D) The approach to asymptotics of prime number things often seems to be rather slow.